# extracting text from a line in R

Tags: r

I am having the below line:

```
opening<-read.csv("Z:\\opening quantity\\20221025NT\\No Of Sales - 20221025.csv")
```

Say I would like to extract the date (20221025), may I know how should I do? Thank you so much.

Comment: From the path? Lots of ways, e.g. `readr::parse_number(basename("Z:\\opening quantity\\20221025NT\\No Of Sales - 20221025.csv"))`.

Comment: Or `sub(".* - (\\d+)\\.csv$", "\\1", basename("Z:\\opening quantity\\20221025NT\\No Of Sales - 20221025.csv"))`, @Axeman's suggestion `parse_number` doesn't work.

Comment: @RuiBarradas,@Axeman, thanks so much, yea the latter one works well :)

Comment: @RuiBarradas works fine for me!